# 3D Pie Chart, Triggering a Tooltip on chart init

Tags: google-visualization

Is there anyway to trigger a mouseover event for a specific pie chart slice that will that slice's tooltip appear through the "ready" event?

My code right now is as follows:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(google_chart, 'ready', function () {
    google_chart.setSelection([{row: 0, column: null}]);
});
```

setSelection() doesn't appear to trigger the tooltip.

I am using Google charts on a mobile web app and want to avoid using legends so that the chart has the most amount of real estate possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no way to trigger the built-in tooltip on init. However you can hook-up a custom tooltip component which triggers at startup.